# User Roles to Upload Products

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a Magento (1.9) store and I want other people to be able to upload and manage their own products. Is this possible using the Users/Roles in Magento or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to "System -> Permissions -> Roles"
2. Click "Add New Role"
3. Give it a name
4. Under "Role Resources" chose "Custom" and check "Catalog". You might want to remove sub-acls
5. Under "System -> Permissions -> Users" create a new user
6. Under "User Role" assign the newly created role

In case users need to be able to edit different store views, this access can be limited using the Enterprise version.

Comment: Thank, but what I am looking for it that they can only manage their own products, rather than the whole catalog.

Comment: Did You found the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

User permissions by product or category are available as extensions at the magento connect. Search for advanced permissions for example.